# Sources for Free High-Resolution (4m or below) Orthophotography (Aerial Photography)

Tags: aerial-photography, orthophoto, orthorectification

Does anyone know of reliable sites that provide high resolution Orthophotography for The USA?

I am not looking for Satellite Imagery. This is limited to Aerial Photography (Orthophotography) or Ortho Drone imagery in raster format - The data will be for Satellite Imagery Orthorectification.

Comment: If it's open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.  If you decide to only ask here then I think your question is too broad because it seeks to compile a list of sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Earth Explorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) has 1m [NAIP imagery](https://www.fsa.usda.gov/programs-and-services/aerial-photography/imagery-programs/naip-imagery/) for the US.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try the USGS data portal:
https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/
I have acquired data below 4 m from the site. You use their search tool and select what you are interested in and apply the proper filters.
You can also use the national map to source other data from the US
https://www.usgs.gov/core-science-systems/national-geospatial-program/national-map.